# apt: Check for package rename

Tags: apt, bash, scripts

I would like to see if there is a way to check if a package got renamed/removed from package repositories on a new Ubuntu release(ex 20.04 --> 20.10). This also applies to packages in other package repositories(already added to apt's cache).
I have thought of using

```bsh
apt show $PACKAGE_NAME > /dev/null
```

and checking the exit status of the command to see if that particular package exists.

Comment: Since 21.04 has not be released yet any question regarding it is off topic.

Comment: @David fixed example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `rmadison` command, included with the `devscripts` package. It's a simple python3 script (you can edit it) that queries the madison databases for each release.

Here's an example of `rmadison` in action. Let's look at the `chromium-browser` package, which changed a couple years ago. The deb package was replaced by a placeholder that merely installs the snap package. You can easily see the difference.

```
$ rmadison chromium-browser
 chromium-browser | 18.0.1025.151~r130497-0ubuntu1                | precise/universe          | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 32.0.1700.107-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~20140204.866.1 | precise-security/universe | armel
 chromium-browser | 32.0.1700.107-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~20140204.866.1 | precise-updates/universe  | armel
 chromium-browser | 34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2                        | trusty/universe           | source, amd64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 37.0.2062.120-0ubuntu0.12.04.4                | precise-security/universe | source, amd64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 37.0.2062.120-0ubuntu0.12.04.4                | precise-updates/universe  | source, amd64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233                   | xenial/universe           | source, amd64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                | trusty-security/universe  | source, amd64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                | trusty-updates/universe   | source, amd64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1                        | bionic/universe           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 80.0.3987.163-0ubuntu1                        | focal/universe            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf
 chromium-browser | 89.0.4389.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.2                 | xenial-security/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 89.0.4389.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.2                 | xenial-updates/universe   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 89.0.4389.90-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                 | bionic-security/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 89.0.4389.90-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                 | bionic-updates/universe   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386
 chromium-browser | 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               | focal-updates/universe    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf
 chromium-browser | 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2                       | groovy/universe           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf
 chromium-browser | 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2                       | hirsute/universe          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf
```

Comment: That is helpful, but not exactly what I was looking for. In addition, after checking `rmadison`, it does only do system repositories (not repositories added by me).

Comment: Also, I think a better version of your answer would use `sudo apt update && apt-cache madison $PACKAGE_NAME` because that includes packages not in system repos.